# Json parsing without array in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have working json parsing codes like below but it takes with array and gives me when use it.

> Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x10ad77178) to 'NSArray' (0x10ad76b88) Error

My json file ( Only will change decimal values inside my json )

```
{
  "One": 30.00,
  "Two": 6.00,
  "Two2": 36.00
}
```

My Swift codes under below

```
            let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://url.com")!
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            let task = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request) {
                (
                let location, let response, let error) in

                guard let _:NSURL = location, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
                    print("error")
                    return
                }

                let urlContents = try! NSString(contentsOfURL: location!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                guard let _:NSString = urlContents else {
                    print("error")
                    return
                }

                let data = urlContents.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
                do {
                    let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)

                    for name in json as! [AnyObject] {
                        if let Onebir = name["One"] as? String {
                            self.One1.text = Onebir

                        }

                    }

                    for names in json as! [AnyObject] {
                        if let Twoiki = names["Two"] as? String {
                            self.Two2.text = Twoiki

                        }

                    }

                    for namesu in json as! [AnyObject] {
                        if let Two2uc = namesu["Two2"] as? String {
                            self.Two23.text = Two2uc

                        }

                    }



                } catch {
                    print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
                }





            }

            task.resume()
```

I try to delete for name .. for names .. for namesu .. but It didn't resolve it.

I need to get clear, want output like this.

```
self.One1.text  = 30.00
self.Two2.text  = 6.00
self.Two23.text = 36.00
```

Comment: Hmm... friendly advice, mate: `guard let _:NSURL = location, let _:NSURLResponse = response`... `guard let _:NSString = urlContents else` I remember telling you weeks ago that this code, which is coming from an infamously bad blog, is absolutely ridiculous - I'm surprised you continue to use it! Please consider not using this anymore. Using `guard` like this is very wrong, you're doing the work twice! :) Please have a look at existing examples on SO you will find much better than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is `Dictionary` not `Array` so access the `Dictionary` like this also your value is `float` type not `String`.

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as [String: Float]

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.One1.text = "\(json["One"])"
    self.Two2.text = "\(json["Two"])"
    self.Two3.text = "\(json["Two2"])"
})
```

Comment: mate also when i click button to run thats update texts about 10-15 secods after how can i get values fastly ? my codes right ?

Comment: @NDoc It's unrelated to network speed, it's because OP is updating the labels in the background - it should be done on the main thread.

Comment: why not `as? [String:Double]` or `as? [String:Float]` ? That avoids the other optional bindings. But you need to force unwrap the values anyway, however it's safe.

Answer (score 1):

The error is itself showing that the response is in the form of `NSDictionary` not in `NSArray` in which you are trying to get.

probably `[]` square brackets deliver data in `Array` and sign `{}` curly brackets  always contains `dictionary` so you must aware about it.